# How do I use start-job within powershell in a foreach loop?

Tags: powershell-3.0

For now, I have commented out the code that isn't working and I am able to single thread this with no problem.  My goal is to fire off four jobs (one for each folder I need to copy with robocopy) and then wait for them to complete.

I have tried the start-job cmdlet in a couple of different places to no avail.

```
$destination = Read-Host 'Please supply the Destination hostname'
$folders = @("folder1","folder2","folder3","folder4")
foreach ($source_folder in $folders)
{
#Start-Job -Name FolderCreateProcess -ScriptBlock {
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Now creating folder structure for " + $source_folder
$robocopystring = $robocopy + " " + "d:\" + $source_folder + " " + "\\" + $destination + "\" + $source_folder + " " + $robocopy_create_options + " /log:" + $robocopy_log_path + "\phase_1_create_" + $source_folder + "_log_" + $(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmm) + ".txt"
Invoke-Expression $robocopystring
#}
}
}
```

I would expect this to start a job for each folder in the background and let them run multi-threaded.  In actuality, it starts four jobs but they end as quickly as they start and there is no log file produced.

Comment: What is $robocopy?  There's an extra curly brace at the end.  Does receive-job show any errors?  Make sure the variables work inside the job.  Why don't you just run robocopy?

Comment: $robocopy = "C:\windows\system32\Robocopy.exe"

Comment: I know robocopy has the /mt for multi-threading but I am unable to get it to fire off multiple jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs are running in different scope, so variables from ouside of a scriptblock are not available. You could use scope modifiers, or pass variables as parameters.

Here job scriptblock is defined separately, not inline with start-job - it helps with readability:

```
$RobocopyScriptBlock= {
  param($src,$dest)
  #your code
}
```

Then to run it:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $RobocopyScriptBlock -ArgumentList $source_folder,$destination -Name 'jobname'
```

You didn't post the part when you check on your jobs after starting them. If you're not doing that, the jobs won't return results and errors by themselves and you won't even see what's wrong. Read more about `Receive-Job`, `Get-Job` and `Remove-Job` cmdlets.

Comment: Adam, I am not following this.  I think I understand that the variables are not being picked up by start-job though.  I am getting confused by what you mean where you say #your code.  I am not sure where to put this in my code with regard to defining the parameters.  Sorry that I am not getting it!

Comment: What I am looking to do here is give an array of folder names, and then start robocopy on all of those folders at once.  It would be kind of like how you run something in the background on Linux with the ampersand (&).  So if I have four folders to copy, it launches a robocopy process in the background (4 of them in this case) for all four folders.  Make sense?

Comment: Or maybe I am going about this all wrong and need to use Start-Process?  Not sure.